# CSS stack elements from bottom-right (row by row, order is important, elements are of diferent widths)

Tags: css

Example of what I need to get:

```
    9 8
7 6 5 4
3 2 1 0
```

I tried using

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

but what I get is:

```
    8 9
4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3
```

which is not sufficient as ordering is important.
Also I thought of grid, but since width of elements vary it was not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **`flex-direction: row-reverse`**:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.container > div {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid;
  counter-increment: num;
}

.container > div::before {
  content: counter(num);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I had it but was getting strange results when building the list using data.reverse().map(), while with data.map().reverse() I get what I wanted. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the css `order` property if you put each number in an element to select. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp.

Editing because of downvote: I suggested this because when I read the question I thought the emphasis was on "order is important", meaning the order could very well change at some point and it needs to be flexible. An example of what I had in mind: https://jsfiddle.net/nr7vqw2e/.

If you are simply wanting to reverse the row then the answer by @Caro will get you there.